# Is there any way to create a group in pidgin like in WhatsApp?

Tags: pidgin, xmpp

I have been using pidgin to chat with my fellow colleagues. If I have to convey any message to of them, I need to send by opening individual chats. So if there is an option to create a group, I can easily send messages to all of them at once. How to create a group in pidgin to chat like in whatsApp groups?

Comment: Are you using your own XMPP server? Or are you connecting to external chat services?

Comment: Own XMPP server

Comment: AFAIK you need to create Rooms in the XMPP server, then join the room. https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html